# Cannot find a (Map) Key deserializer for type [simple type, class java.time.OffsetDateTime

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization

I have a class that I cannot change with the following format:

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
public class MyClass {
    private OffsetDateTime updateDate;
    ...
}
```

I receive this data as json and I try to map back to the class I need:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
...
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
MyClass myObj = mapper.readValue(jsonData, MyClass.class);
```

And I get the following:

```
Cannot find a (Map) Key deserializer for type [simple type, class java.time.OffsetDateTime
```

I also have sub-classes in this main class that also return an OffsetDateTime.

```
{
  "updateDate":{
  "offset":{
     "totalSeconds":0,
     "id":"Z",
     "rules":{
        "transitions":[
           
        ],
        "transitionRules":[
           
        ],
        "fixedOffset":true
     }
  },
  "nano":935767000,
  "year":2020,
  "monthValue":10,
  "dayOfMonth":8,
  "hour":15,
  "minute":33,
  "second":0,
  "month":"OCTOBER",
  "dayOfWeek":"THURSDAY",
  "dayOfYear":282
}
}
```

Can I get some help here? :)

Thank you!

Comment: Show us the json

Comment: @Eklavya updated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I would try really hard to convince the other side to change their format (it should be obvious to anyone that the current one has a lot of redundancy and is hard to use), and send the date as ISO-8601 string, for example. This way you could use Jackson-Datatype-JSR310 module to deserialize your object.

If it's not possible to make changes to the format, them you'll have to write your own custom deserializer for it.

Comment: Yea I believe that's the best thing to do @mov :)